# Pass Dash Dropdown Selection To Variable

Tags: python, api, flask, plotly-dash

I am having trouble getting a parameter to inherit a user dropdown selection in my dashboard.

Below are the three parts of my code. I don't believe the issue is in the layout/graphing section because I am able to get the graphs to populate if I remove the Dropdown object and assign the `boro` variable explicitly (i.e. uncomment the first line in section 1). Furthermore, if I test without the graphing, and just attempt to print the variable value, it still shows up blank when using the dropdown.

Can anybody provide some assistance? I am working off of the examples given in the Plotly Dash tutorial (https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/dropdown), but I am not sure I am translating them correctly.

Part 1: pull data from API

```
#boro = 'Bronx'
def getHealth(boro):
    health_url = ('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/nwxe-4ae8.json?' +\
            '$select=health,count(tree_id)' +\
            '&$where=boroname=\'' + boro + '\'' +\
            '&$group=health').replace(' ', '%20')
    health_trees = pd.read_json(health_url)

def getStew(boro):
    stew_url = ('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/nwxe-4ae8.json?' +\
            '$select=steward,health,count(tree_id)' +\
            '&$where=boroname=\'' + boro + '\'' +\
            '&$group=steward,health').replace(' ', '%20')
    stew_trees = pd.read_json(stew_url)
```

Part 2: Set layout, create graphs

```
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Trees Overview'),

    html.Div(children='''
        HEALTH QUALITY
    '''),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in trees.boroname.unique()],
        value='Bronx',
        clearable=False
    ),
    html.Div(id='table-container'),
])

def generateGraphs(df1,df2,df3):
    return dcc.Graph(
        id='graph1',
        figure={
            'data': [
                go.Pie(labels=df1['health'],values=df1['count_tree_id']),
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Count By Species'
            }
        }
    ),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='graph2',
        figure={
            'data': [
                go.Bar(x=df2[df2['steward']==i]['health']
                       ,y=df2[df2['steward']==i]['count_tree_id']
                       ,name=i
                       ,marker=go.bar.Marker(
                    color='rgb(26, 118, 255)'
                ))
                for i in df3['steward'].unique()
            ]
        }
    )
```

Part 3: this is where I believe the problem is. Am I using the `@app.callback` function properly? Am I defining `retHealth()` and calling `generateGraphs()` properly?

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('table-container', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('dropdown', 'value')])
def retHealth(value):
    health=getHealth(value)
    stew=getStew(value)
    return generateGraphs(health,stew,trees)
```

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this error.  The only thing I did differently was not using list comprehension in your `options` section because I don't have that data.  Are you able to `print` value along the way and see where it fails?

Comment: @Carlos to be clear, I don't get any error, I just don't get any output (blank page under "Trees Overview" header). And I tried debugging using `print(boro)` but it returns nothing, which is what leads me to believe the dropdown is not populating that parameter

Comment: Not sure if it's possible but could you `pastebin` a more complete code?  I tested this code (removing the items that couldn't resolve) and the behavior was not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback is fine.

The problem is that you don't return anything inside `getHealth` and `getStew`. Which means `None` is returned implicitly.

So change these functions to return the DataFames used for plotting the graphs:

```
def getHealth(boro):
    health_url = (
        "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/nwxe-4ae8.json?"
        + "$select=health,count(tree_id)"
        + "&$where=boroname='"
        + boro
        + "'"
        + "&$group=health"
    ).replace(" ", "%20")
    return pd.read_json(health_url)


def getStew(boro):
    stew_url = (
        "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/nwxe-4ae8.json?"
        + "$select=steward,health,count(tree_id)"
        + "&$where=boroname='"
        + boro
        + "'"
        + "&$group=steward,health"
    ).replace(" ", "%20")
    return pd.read_json(stew_url)
```

Comment: I no longer have the original code to test out this answer, but looking back, this seems like the likely culprit. Thank you!